# In-App purchases freezes and crashes my app after canMakePayments is called

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit, selector

Amateur here. The code works well when the BUY button is pressed (I used breakpoints to pick the line with issues, see below) until the `canMakePayments` is called. Scenes that take care of IAP are `Gamescene`, `InAppManager`, `InAppObserver`, `ORPurchaseProduct`; all the relevant code is provided below.

My app crashes after `break`. Everything works fine until the `break` line. This is inside `InAppManager.m`. Scroll down to see all the code in `InAppManager.m`. After the app crashes, the IAP sort of continues to show the alertView asking me to buy. After clicking buy the alertView disappears and the app does not respond to any touches. When I close the app and open it, it shows that I have purchased the product, and everything works well from there. I shared all the information, Thanks in advance.

Can someone show me the directions please.

```
-(void) buyFeature:(NSString*) featureID {

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSLog(@"Can make payments");
        SKProduct* selectedProduct;

        for (int i=0; i < [purchaseableProducts count]; i++) {
            selectedProduct = [purchaseableProducts objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([[selectedProduct productIdentifier] isEqualToString:featureID]) {

                // if we found a SKProduct in the purchaseableProducts array with the same ID as the one we want to buy, we proceed by putting it in the payment queue.

                SKPayment* payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

                NSLog(@"Proceeding by putting the product in the payment queue");

                break;

            }
            else {

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't purchase from the App Store" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like in the console after the crash

```
2015-01-03 20:51:09.244 My App Name[1785:95544] Proceeding by putting the product in the payment queue
2015-01-03 20:51:10.369 My App Name[1785:95544] -[ORPurchaseProduct setGamePaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf9b417ce0
2015-01-03 20:51:10.389 My App Name[1785:95544] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ORPurchaseProduct setGamePaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf9b417ce0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed55f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e697bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed5d04d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecb527c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecb4e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   My App Name                         0x000000010dcd3d88 -[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] + 216
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f535d96 -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 338
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed25cec __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecdf72e ____CFXNotificationPostToken_block_invoke + 142
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec8b53c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec81285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec80a67 __CFRunLoopRun + 887
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec80486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110dee9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010f53b420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    15  My App Name                         0x000000010dcfaf03 main + 115
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001111da145 start + 1
    17  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is how the whole code in InAppPurchase.m looks like

```
@interface InAppManager () {

    NSMutableArray* purchaseableProducts; // an array of possible products to purchase
    NSUserDefaults* defaults; // store a bool variable marking products that have been unlocked
    bool product1WasPurchased; // YES or NO

    InAppObserver* theObserver;

}

@end

@implementation InAppManager

static NSString* productID1 = @"MyProduct";


static InAppManager* sharedManager = nil;

+(InAppManager*) sharedManager {

    if(sharedManager == nil) {

        sharedManager = [[InAppManager alloc] init];

    }

    return sharedManager;
}

-(id) init {

    if  ((self = [super init])) {

        //do initialization

        sharedManager = self;
        defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        product1WasPurchased = [defaults boolForKey:productID1]; 


        purchaseableProducts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self requestProductData]; 

        theObserver = [[InAppObserver alloc] init];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:theObserver];
    }

    return self;

}

-(void) requestProductData {

    SKProductsRequest* request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:productID1, nil]]; 

    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}


-(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {



    NSArray* skProducts = response.products; 

    if ( [skProducts count] != 0 && [purchaseableProducts count] == 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [skProducts count]; i++) {

            [purchaseableProducts addObject:[skProducts objectAtIndex:i]];
            SKProduct* product = [purchaseableProducts objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"Feature: %@, Cost: %f, ID: %@", [product localizedTitle], [[product price] doubleValue], [product productIdentifier] );

        }

    }

    NSLog(@" We found %lu In-App Purchases in iTunes Connect", (unsigned long)[purchaseableProducts count]);

}


-(void) failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*) transaction{

    NSString* failMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reason: %@, You can try: %@", [transaction.error localizedFailureReason], [transaction.error localizedRecoverySuggestion]  ];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unable to complete your purchase" message:failMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}
-(void) provideContent:(NSString*) productIdentifier{


    NSNotificationCenter* notification = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 

    if ( [productIdentifier isEqualToString:productID1]) {
        product1WasPurchased = YES;
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:productID1];
        [notification postNotificationName:@"feature1Purchased" object:nil];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you!" message:@"You have purchased MyProduct" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Something happened!");
    }


}


-(void) buyFeature1 {

    [self buyFeature:productID1];

}

-(void) buyFeature:(NSString*) featureID {

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSLog(@"Can make payments");
        SKProduct* selectedProduct;

        for (int i=0; i < [purchaseableProducts count]; i++) {
            selectedProduct = [purchaseableProducts objectAtIndex:i];

            if ([[selectedProduct productIdentifier] isEqualToString:featureID]) {

                SKPayment* payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

                NSLog(@"Proceeding by putting the product in the payment queue");

                break;

            }
            else {

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh no" message:@"You can't purchase from the App Store" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

            }

        }
    }
}

-(bool) isFeature1PurchasedAlready {

    return product1WasPurchased;
}


-(void) restoreCompletedTransactions{

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}
```

This is how the whole code looks like in InAppObserver.m

```
#import "InAppObserver.h"
#import "InAppManager.h"  

@implementation InAppObserver

-(void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    NSLog(@"Payment queue options");

    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

}

-(void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*) transaction {
    NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");

    //if the error was anything other than the user cancelling it

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {

        [[InAppManager sharedManager] failedTransaction:transaction];

        NSLog(@"%@", [transaction.error localizedDescription]);

    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

}

-(void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*) transaction {
    NSLog(@"Transaction Completion");

    //when we pass the transaction back to the sharedManager it has the product ID

    [[InAppManager sharedManager] provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

-(void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction*) transaction {
    NSLog(@"Transaction Restored");

     [[InAppManager sharedManager] provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

@end
```

I have these lines in GameScene, where everything starts, I only chose the relevant code.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

[InAppManager sharedManager];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(unlockProduct1) name:@"feature1Purchased" object:nil];
}

-(void) unlockProduct1 {

    NSLog(@"this class knows we purchased the product!");

}
```

I have these lines in a ORPurchaseProduct.m. Here I have the buy button and it checks if the product is bought already. I transition to this from GameScene.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
[InAppManager sharedManager];

if ( [[InAppManager sharedManager] isFeature1PurchasedAlready] == NO) {
    NSLog(@" product was not bought yet");
    [self createBuyButton:@"BUY"];

} else {
    NSLog(@" product was bought");
    [self createBuyButton:alreadyBoughtMessage];
}
}

-(void) createBuyButton:(NSString*) theMessage {

    UIFont* theFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BUY" size:18];

    thePurchaseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    if( [theMessage isEqualToString:alreadyBoughtMessage]) {

        [thePurchaseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doNothing) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSLog(@"Already bought message: we are here");

    } else {

        [thePurchaseButton addTarget:[InAppManager sharedManager] action:@selector(buyFeature1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    [thePurchaseButton.titleLabel setFont:theFont];
    [thePurchaseButton setTitle:theMessage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [thePurchaseButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [thePurchaseButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    thePurchaseButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 380, 160, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:thePurchaseButton];      
}

-(void)doNothing
{
    NSLog(@"Nothing to be done because the product is already bought!");
}
```

Comment: The crash log suggests that you try to call `setGamePaused:` or try to set a variable called `gamePaused` on an instance of `ORPurchaseProduct`. try adding an exception breakpoint and see where the exception is throwed.

Comment: @AMI289 I have this code in the applicationWillResignActive (in the AppDelegate.m)`SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    ((GameScene *)view.scene).gamePaused = YES;` and I also have it in the GameScene as you can see from the line. Maybe the issue comes from this, but I can't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out this line of code and everything worked out, it was in the AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive method.Thank you guys

```
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
((GameScene *)view.scene).gamePaused = YES;
```